# What are opening and closing double quotes? And how do I redefine it to be something else?

Tags: symbols, punctuation, ligatures

I have a LaTeX document written with normal English quotes, eg.:

```
``This is a quoted text.''
```

Now, I would like to redefine ``` `` ``` and `''`, so the *combination* of two `` ` `` characters is substituted with, say, `<` and `>`. The result should be as if I had written:

```
<This is a quoted text.>
```

I find that I miss the Latex vocabulary for describing and searching for the issue. What is ``` `` ``` at all? A two glyph character? A command? A macro? What is its relation to `` ` ``?

Comment: Have you seen the package [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes)?

Comment: Yes, that's why I began digging into this. I want to transparently switch my document to `csquotes`.

Comment: Then just replace `\`\`` with `\\enquote{` and `''` with `}`

Comment: @Mico Not really; the ligature substitution happens deep down TeX's bowels, at the typesetting stage.

Comment: @yo' But then I need to change the text in my document. I am looking for something I can just place in the preamble so that I can easily redefine it later and only in a single place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally `'` and `` ` `` are simple characters that, when found in normal text, are passed unchanged to TeX’s *stomach* where paragraphs are split into lines, boxes are built and pages are formed.

When paragraphs are split into lines, TeX recognizes ligatures, for instance changing `fi` into a single glyph (but remembering the two original ones in case hyphenation between the two letters is needed).

The same happens with the combinations

```
`` ''
```

that are converted into “ and ” respectively. For instance, the input

```
``word''
```

is converted, when boxes are formed, into

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 \ (ligature ``)
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 w
....\kern-0.27779
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 " (ligature '')
```

At the same stage, automatic kerning based on font information takes place. Indeed, the ligatures are programmed into the font and are out of the user’s control.

You could make `` ` `` and `'` into *active* characters, so basically the same as macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\myleftquote{\futurelet\next\left@quote@check}
\protected\def\myrightquote{\futurelet\next\right@quote@check}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`` \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\left@quote@check{\ifx\next~<\expandafter\@gobble\else`\fi}
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`' \lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\right@quote@check{\ifx\next~>\expandafter\@gobble\else'\fi}
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`` \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\myleftquote
\begingroup\lccode`~=`' \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\myrightquote
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode``=\active
  \catcode`'=\active
}

\begin{document}

A ``word'' and more

A `word' and more

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this is quite fragile. As you see, the code is written in a very indirect way, doing the activation at the very last moment, because `` ` `` and `'` also have syntactic meaning.

For instance, you won't be able to use `\symbol{'123}` (an octal number according to TeX syntax) in the document, because `'` would be an unexpected token in that context, being active. You also lose the “Spanish” ligatures `` `? `` and `` `! `` for ¿ and ¡ (this might be arranged for, with more tests).

You should also fix the behavior of `` ` `` in verbatim modes.

Comment: This is the answer, I was looking for. It can be done, but not without technical debt. I discussed it with my study group and we decided to convert our documents to `csqoutes` format for robustness. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are able and willing to run LuaLaTeX, you can (a) set up a Lua function that does the string substitution work and (b) assign this function to the `process_input_buffer` callback, which operates at a very early stage, *before* TeX's "eyes", "mouth", etc. start their work.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % handle "<" and ">" in text mode

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function change_quotes ( buff )
   return ( string.gsub ( buff, "``(.-)''", "<%1>" ) )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", change_quotes, "change_quotes")
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
``This is a quoted text.'' 

Here are ``three'' ``quoted'' ``words''.  

This is an ``'' empty quote.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the character substitutions are not supposed to happen in `verbatim` and `Verbatim` environments, the code of the Lua function needs to be extended a bit to check. Basically, the code has to check if the material being scanned by the function is in a verbatim-type environment. This can be handled by replacing the code shown above between the `\begin{luacode}` and `\end{luacode}` lines with the following code:

```
\begin{luacode}
in_verbatim = false  -- Set up a Boolean variable
function change_quotes ( buff )
   if string.find ( buff , "\\begin{[vV]erbatim}" ) then
      in_verbatim = true
      return buff
   elseif string.find ( buff , "\\end{[vV]erbatim}" ) then
      in_verbatim = false
      return buff
   elseif in_verbatim == false then
      return string.gsub ( buff , "``(.-)''" , "<%1>" ) 
   end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", change_quotes, "change_quotes")
\end{luacode}
```

Comment: LuaLatex seems very interesting suggestion, but unfortunately we are dependent on pdflatex.